# Presaturated ideals

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9605234), Gitik and Shelah make the following claim (part of Proposition 1.5):

> **Claim (Gitik-Shelah):** Suppose $\kappa < \lambda$ are regular, $2^\lambda = \lambda^+$, and $D$ is a normal ideal on $\lambda$. If forcing with $D^+$ makes $cf(\lambda^+) < \kappa$, then it collapses all cardinals in some interval $(\alpha,\lambda^+]$ where $\alpha < \kappa$.

I do not understand the argument for this claim.  An interesting dichotomy follows:

> **Corollary:** If GCH holds and $\eta$ is a singular cardinal, then for every normal ideal $D$ on $\eta^+$, either $D$ is presaturated or forcing with $D$ collapses $\eta$.

Sketch of proof: Assume $D$ is not presaturated but $D^+$ preserves that $\eta$ is a cardinal.  Since $D$ is not presaturated, forcing with $D^{+}$ collapses $\eta^{++}$, and since $|D^+| = \eta^{++}$, it preserves $\eta^{+3}$.  By a well-known theorem of Shelah, this implies that $cf(\eta^{++}) = cf(\eta) < \eta$ in the extension by $D^+$.  But by the Claim, $\eta$ is collapsed, a contradiction.

However, it seems that we should be able to force a counterexample to this dichotomy from large cardinals, but I am probably missing some subtlety.  So my question is, how do you prove the Claim?

Comment: By Lemma 4.9 page 440 of Shelah's book ``proper forcing'', we must have in the generic extension, $cf(\lambda^+)=cf(|\lambda^+|)$.

Comment: Yes, I am using this theorem in my corollary, but I don't see how it implies the claim.

Comment: Maybe a simple question in your argument. In your argument for applying Shelah's result, you seem use $\eta^{++}$ is collapsed into $\eta.$ Why this is true? in other words why $\eta^+$ is also collapsed?

Comment: Simply because $\eta^+$ is the critical point of the generic embedding, so the ultrapower thinks that $\eta^+$ is an ordinal of cardinality $\eta$.  In the non-precipitous case we use the fact that the generic ultrapower is well-founded at least up to $\eta^{++}$ (using canonical functions).

Comment: @Mohammad: Does this theorem appear in Proper and Improper Forcing somewhere as well?

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, it is removed there, but you can see it in Shelah's book "Cardinal arithemtic", page 304 (again Lemma 4.9!!)

Comment: @Mohammad: Thanks. I'll look at it when I'm at the university later today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result follows from the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** Suppose $\kappa$ is a regular uncountable cardinal and $|P|\leq \kappa.$ Then $\Vdash_P cf(\kappa)=|\kappa|.$

In your case $D^+$ has size $\lambda^+$ and it forces $cf(\lambda^+)<\kappa.$ So by above theorem it also forces $|\lambda^+|<\kappa.$

For a proof of the above theorem, see my answer given in [Singularizing forcing of "small" cardinality?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142086/singularizing-forcing-of-small-cardinality)

Comment: So the surprising dichotomy is true.